# Not displaying output in Maple for for-do loop

Tags: maple

I am trying to write something that displays a rotating square. However, the output is

```
display(PLOT(...), PLOT(...), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), insequence = true)
```

My for-do code is

```
for k to 30 do 
 RotSquare := Trans(1.5, 1.5).HomRot((1/15)*k*Pi).Trans(-1.5, -1.5).HomSquare; 
 graph[k] := plot(Transpose(`<,>`(RotSquare[1], RotSquare[2])), x = -3 .. 3, y = -3 .. 3) 
 od:
 display(seq(graph[k], k = 1 .. 30), insequence = true)
```

However my output is

```
 display(PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), PLOT(`...`), insequence = true)
```

I was wondering if anyone knows whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you load the "plots" module.  Either reference display as `plots[display]` or use `with(plots)` in initializing your worksheet.

Comment: Realized I misspelled with(plots). Thank you